# Google Cartographer: Internal coordinate systems

Tags: c++, math, ros, coordinate-transformation, slam

I am studying Google Cartographer SLAM. Working with submaps in the library API (which is not at all documented) I discovered the following entities representing coordinates:

- Trajectory (list of sensor poses with connected submaps)
- Global pose (submap pose).
- Local pose.
- Slice pose.

Here are the lines of code implementing this in [`submap_painter.cc`](https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer/blob/877157a0d91788a7700221d87232d412cb3c1ef4/cartographer/io/submap_painter.cc#L41):

```cpp
void CairoPaintSubmapSlices(
    const double scale,
    const std::map<::cartographer::mapping::SubmapId, SubmapSlice>& submaps,
    cairo_t* cr, std::function<void(const SubmapSlice&)> draw_callback) {
  cairo_scale(cr, scale, scale);

  for (auto& pair : submaps) {
    const auto& submap_slice = pair.second;
    if (submap_slice.surface == nullptr) {
      return;
    }
    const Eigen::Matrix4d homo =
        ToEigen(submap_slice.pose * submap_slice.slice_pose).matrix();

    cairo_save(cr);
    cairo_matrix_t matrix;
    cairo_matrix_init(&matrix, homo(1, 0), homo(0, 0), -homo(1, 1), -homo(0, 1),
                      homo(0, 3), -homo(1, 3));
    cairo_transform(cr, &matrix);

    const double submap_resolution = submap_slice.resolution;
    cairo_scale(cr, submap_resolution, submap_resolution);

    // Invokes caller's callback to utilize slice data in global cooridnate
    // frame. e.g. finds bounding box, paints slices.
    draw_callback(submap_slice);
    cairo_restore(cr);
  }
}
```

where `submap_slice.pose` is a global pose of the submap in the global coordinates, and `submap_slice.slice_pose` seems to be a local position of the 2D submap in the map formulated before. The global position is defined in meters, as it is scaled by map resolution, and the slice pose then should be defined in pixels. `ToEigen` function is defined [here](https://github.com/cartographer-project/cartographer/blob/877157a0d91788a7700221d87232d412cb3c1ef4/cartographer/io/submap_painter.cc#L26) as:

```cpp
Eigen::Affine3d ToEigen(const ::cartographer::transform::Rigid3d& rigid3) {
  return Eigen::Translation3d(rigid3.translation()) * rigid3.rotation();
}
```

representing the standard quaternion-based orientation of the 3D rigid body for Cartographer.

I am wondering if there is a way to reproduce these coordinate transformations and rebuild a map produced by Cartographer, but using **OpenCV** instead of Cairo. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: For reference purposes, here is the code snippet allowing you to decode and process the `.pbstream` file generated by Cartographer: https://gist.github.com/twdragon/b63bef366cb84c3e75da983f8c12ea4f